# How to inject code you don't control in InversifyJS

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

Is it possible to inject classes that you can't edit? It seems Inversify is heavily dependent on annotations/decorators but is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [inversify wiki](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/inheritance.md#what-can-i-do-when-my-base-class-is-provided-by-a-third-party-module):

> In some cases you may get errors about missing annotations classes 
>   provided by a third party modul like:
>
> > Error: Missing required @injectable annotation in: SamuraiMaster
>
> You can overcome this problem using the decorate function:
>
> ```
> import { decorate, injectable } from "inversify";
> import SomeClass from "some-module";
>
> decorate(injectable(), SomeClass);
> return SomeClass;
> ```
>
> Check out the [JS example](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/basic_js_example.md)
>   page on the wiki for more info.

You can also check out the [inversify-vanillajs-helpers](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-vanillajs-helpers) project.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that.